# alarm iphone sdk issues

Tags: iphone, avaudioplayer, uilocalnotification, avplayer

Here is some code.

```
UIApplication *app  = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    NSArray *oldNotifications  = [app scheduledLocalNotifications];

    if ([oldNotifications count] > 0) [app cancelAllLocalNotifications];


    NSString *filePath = [DOCUMENTS stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"personal2.wav"];
    //NSLog(@"%@",filePath);
    //filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"wolf" ofType:@"wav"];
    UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
    localNotif.fireDate = alarmPicker.date ;
    localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
    localNotif.alertBody = @"Alarm";
    localNotif.alertAction = @"View";
    localNotif.soundName = filePath;
    localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
    //localNotif.repeatInterval = NSYearCalendarUnit;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
    [localNotif release];
```

So it shows just alert but it is not playing wav. When i click View it starts the app and in didReceiveLocalNotification method i play this song again and it sounds good.
Can somebody help me with issue. Thanks

P.S. I read that duration of wav should be les than 30 sec and it is 22 seconds so it should play
P.S.2 Is it a way to repeat of playing the song when the localnotifications fires up. THANKS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you have `App plays audio` in `Required background modes` in your app's target properties.

Comment: Check if `UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName` works okay. If it does, you'll need to prepare your sound - convert it to `.caf` using `afconvert` like this: `/usr/bin/afconvert -f caff -d LEI16 {INPUT} {OUTPUT}`.